# How to display part's name instead of input file name when Eclipse is closed?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When Eclipse is closed and there are editor's with unsaved content, Eclipse will show a save dialog which lists all unsaved editors. Am I right in assuming that the editor's input file name is displayed here?

I now have two different types of editors that have the same input file. This means when I close Eclipse, there are two equal entries in the save dialog for two different editors. Can I get Eclipse to display the part's name instead (which I set by calling `setPartName("some name")`)?

Comment: Question not clear. Can you elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your editor implement `ISaveablesSource` Eclipse will call the methods

```
Saveable[] getSaveables()

Saveable[] getActiveSaveables()
```

to get one or more `Saveable` objects to be used for saving.

You can extend the `Saveable` class to override the `getName()` method to return a name which distinguishes your two cases.

If your editor is derived from `AbstractTextEditor` (directly or indirectly) then it already has a `Saveable` defined called `TextEditorSaveable` which you could extend.